# Eloquent count occurrence with where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to do a simple query using Eloquent. My `test_registrants` table looks like this
[image]
I want to add new column with value of all `user_id` with `payment_status = 1`

This is my query using `whereColumn`

```
TestRegistrant::select(['test_registrants.*'])
            ->where('payment_status', 1)
            ->addSelect([
                'attempt' => TestRegistrant::select(DB::raw('count(*) as attempt'))
                    ->whereColumn('test_registrants.user_id', 'user_id')
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('payment_status', 1);
                    })
            ]);
```

but I get all `user_id` instead
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is this one
[image]

So what do I do wrong here? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your query is returning `3`, is because it is simply counting all the records that have `payment_status = 1`. The `whereColumn()` is not working  properly, because it does not reflect the right columns.

When you define an `alias` for the `user_id` column on the `test_registrants` table, it should work. For example, you could name it: `outer_user_id`. I have updated your example accordingly:

```
TestRegistrant::select(['test_registrants.payment_status', 'test_registrants.user_id as outer_user_id'])
  ->where('payment_status', 1)
  ->addSelect([
      'attempt' => TestRegistrant::selectRaw('count(*) as attempt')
          ->whereColumn('test_registrants.user_id', 'outer_user_id')
          ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('payment_status', 1);
          })
        ])
  ->get();
```

Alternatively, you could also look into `grouping` the results, so that you can count all the rows in a specific group.